# Create Partial shipment in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I am getting error on creating an shipment

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to 
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Validation\ShipOrder::Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Validation\ 
{closure}() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentItemCreationInterface, 
instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Item given in /vendor/magento/module- 
sales/Model/Order/Validation/ShipOrder.php:127
```

Here is how I am creating the shipment

```
    <?php

namespace Navien\Custom\Model;

class ShipmentManager 
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $orderInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory
     */
    protected $trackingFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface
     */
    protected $commentInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ShipOrder
     */
    protected $shipOrderService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order
     */
    protected $orderConverter;


    /**
     * ShipmentManager constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //this is instance of my custom class to get instance object manager.
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


        //order interface
        $this->orderInterface = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class
        );

        //instance of tracking factory to add tracking number in shipment
        $this->trackingFactory = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory::class
        );

        //Comment interface to add comment on the shipment.
        $this->commentInterface = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface::class
        );

        //Shipment order service to create shipment
        $this->shipOrderService = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ShipOrder::class
        );

        //Order converter to create shipment items
        $this->orderConverter = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order::class);

    }

    /**
     * Prepares tracking data form tracking number.
     *
     * @param $trackingNumber
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track
     */
    protected function setTrackingData($shippingPartner, $trackingNumber)
    {
        $track = $this->trackingFactory->create();
        $track->setTrackNumber($trackingNumber);
        //Carrier code can not be null/empty. Default carrier code is used
        $track->setCarrierCode('custom'); //Put your carrier code here
        $track->setTitle($shippingPartner); //add your title here
        $trackInfo[] = $track;

        return $trackInfo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $comment
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface
     */
    protected function setShipmentComment($comment)
    {
        //comment can not be empty
        $comment = !empty($comment) ? $comment : 'Not Available';

        return $this->commentInterface->setComment($comment);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createShipment($orderId, array $items, $shippingPartner = "", $trackingNumber = '', $comment = null, $notify = false,  $includeComment = false )
    {
        $order = $this->orderInterface->load($orderId);
        // $order = $this->orderInterface->loadByIncrementId('000000050');


        if ($order->canShip()) {
            try {
                $orderId      = $order->getId();
                $tracks       = $this->setTrackingData($shippingPartner, $trackingNumber);
                $comment      = $this->setShipmentComment($comment);
                $shippedItems = $this->createShipmentItems($items, $order);

                //creates shipment 
                $shipmentId = $this->shipOrderService->execute($orderId,
                    $shippedItems,
                    $notify,
                    $includeComment,
                    $comment,
                    $tracks);

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                return false;
            }

            return $shipmentId;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Create shipment items required to create shipment.
     *
     * @param array                      $items
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function createShipmentItems(array $items, $order)
    {
        $shipmentItem = [];
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            if (array_key_exists($orderItem->getId(), $items)) {
                $shipmentItem[] = $this->orderConverter
                    ->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)
                    ->setQty($items[$orderItem->getId()]);
            }
        }

        return $shipmentItem;
    }
}
```

Some users reported that the class was working on Magento 2.3 but not working on Magento 2.4 . I am using Magento 2.4.2. Can someone help me to find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Shipment for any order Like this

```
// Load the order increment ID
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementID($incrementid);

// OR
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
    ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000001');


//load by order 
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
    ->load('1');

// Check if order can be shipped or has already shipped
if (! $order->canShip()) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
                );
}

// Initialize the order shipment object
$convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
    // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
    if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

    // Create shipment item with qty
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

    // Add shipment item to shipment
    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

// Register shipment
$shipment->register();

$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

try {
    // Save created shipment and order
    $shipment->save();
    $shipment->getOrder()->save();

    // Send email
    $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        ->notify($shipment);

    $shipment->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __($e->getMessage())
                );
}
```

Above I am looping through all the Order Items, you can check the skus which you want to ship with the help of condition so that partial shipment case can be managed.